# Json to Excel python script

Tags: python, json, excel

I have a API which returns JSON response every single time whenever called,
Response example:-

```
{
"data": [
         {"id":1,"name":"A","class":"AA" },
         {"id":2,"name":"B","class":"BB" },
         {"id":3,"name":"C","class":"CC" },
        ]
}
```

I want to create a Excel file from the received response with selected fields in this case just **`id and name`**. Can anyone please tell me how I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: If you Google "python excel", you get dozens of options. You can also just use the Python built-in `csv` library.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Grismar i have tried many ways but couldn't  able to convert it that's why i have asked this question here.

Comment: Really? You have to try really hard to miss this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html and this isn't very hard to find either https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: @Grismar i have created successfully created CSV from json but unable to create Excel directly from it.

Comment: Have a read https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ (or xlsxwriter, or xlwt, or any of many libraries - which is the best is not a question to ask on StackOverflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to convert the JSON data into an dict in python and then convert the data in to csv format (which can be read by excel).

```
import json
import csv

api = "{"data": [
          {"id":1,"name":"A","class":"AA" },
          {"id":2,"name":"B","class":"BB" },
          {"id":3,"name":"C","class":"CC" },
         ]
       }"

data = json.load(api)

f = open('data.csv')
csv_file = csv.writer(f)
for item in data['data']:
    f.writerow(item['id'] + ', ' . item['name']) 
f.close()
```

To answer your question, you could try pandas.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

api = "{"data": [
          {"id":1,"name":"A","class":"AA" },
          {"id":2,"name":"B","class":"BB" },
          {"id":3,"name":"C","class":"CC" },
         ]
       }"

data = json.load(api)
excel_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['data'])

# Then convert to excel xls or csv files
excel_data.to_csv('file.csv')
excel_data.to_excel('file.xls')
```

Comment: Hi @Spot135 Thanks for your response I have already done this is there any other way threw which i can directly convert json to Excel because the data-set is to large and json to csv,and then csv to excel is consuming too much time.